# How can I include data input "controls" within a VBA formula?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to create a worksheet full of correlations that only work for certain data ranges. I'm working to figure out how I can code all of these correlations in VBA so that they will only produce a numerical output if the input data matches the required data range. I'm trying to utilize looping in order to check whether each cell of data fits these "controls" on the data by moving down each column.

For example, here's one of the correlations:

AlMarhoun = (5.38088 * 10 ^ (-3) * Rs ^ (0.715082) * yo ^ (3.1437) * (T + 459.67) ^ (1.32657)) / (yg ^ (1.87784))

with each parameter valid for the following values:

Rs: between 26 and 1602
yo: between 0.8035 and 0.9377
T: between 74 and 240
yg: between .75 and 1.3

I have columns full of data for each of the parameters, and want to weed out the ones that won't work in this correlation. Although primitive, the following code is all I've been able to come up with thus far. I don't have much understanding of the loop function, but perhaps it could be used to move down each column and compare them to the data ranges above. Column C holds the data for the T parameter, Column B holds data for the Rs parameter, etc.

```
Public Function AlMarhoun2(Rs As Double, yo As Double, T As Double, 
'Al-Marhoun correlation from 1988 for bubble point pressure
If Range(C3).Value < 74 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
If Range(C3).Value > 240 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
If Range(B3).Value < 26 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
If Range(B3).Value > 1602 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
If Range(D3).Value < 0.75 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
If Range(D3).Value > 1.3 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
If Range(F3).Value < 0.8035 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
If Range(F3).Value > 0.9377 Then
Range(J3).Value = "Correlation not valid"
AlMarhoun2 = (5.38088 * 10 ^ (-3) * Rs ^ (0.715082) * yo ^ (3.1437)               
End Function
```

I would like to include a message such as "Correlation not valid for these inputs" or something similar if the data does not fit within the correlation range.

Comment: It needs to be `Range("C3")` for a start. Are you saying the correlation shouldn't be run if any number in C is less than 74 etc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first code for an user-define function like below.

Then you can input =AlMarhoun2(B3,C3,D3) in the cell J3 to run the function

```
Public Function AlMarhoun2(Rs As Double, yo As Double, T As Double)as variant

If T < 74 or T > 240 Then
    AlMarhoun2 = "Correlation not valid"
elseif Rs <26 or Rs > 1620 then
    AlMarhoun2 = "Correlation not valid"
'More If condition

Else
    AlMarhoun2 = (5.38088 * 10 ^ (-3) * Rs ^ (0.715082) * yo ^ (3.1437)
End If
End Function
```